# mysql query for send and receiver messages for particular user

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to make query to extract the send and receive messages under specific user.
let suppose I tried to make understand question.

there is list of users and when I click on the user all correspondence data should be come under this specific user.

The query I am using

```
SELECT id,post_id
     , post_auth_user_id
     , ask_user_id
     , response_user_id
     , message
     , updated_at 
  FROM post_queries 
 WHERE (4 IN (ask_user_id,response_user_id) 
       OR 2 IN (ask_user_id)) 
    OR (ask_user_id=4 AND response_user_id=0)
```

but this query is not give me appropriate  result.

I want to all result like in this format.

id  post_id  post_auth_user_id  ask_user_id  response_user_id  message            updated_at

---

```
 1        2                  2            3                 0  asking property  2020-10-10 14:09:14   
 3        2                  2            3                 2  yeh response hei  2020-10-10 15:19:14
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want messages between two users -- say 2 and 4 -- you can use:

```
SELECT id, post_id, post_auth_user_id, ask_user_id, response_user_id, message, updated_at
FROM (ask_user_id = 2 AND response_user_id = 4) OR
     (ask_user_id = 4 AND response_user_id = 2) ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yes its 2 users when I try to run this query its give me this error Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'IN ( (2, 4), (4, 2) )
 LIMIT 0, 1000' at line 2

Comment: @inocent . . . I guess your version of MariaDB doesn't support the tuple syntax.

Comment: Thanks now its working Thankx once again for helping me